# NPM getting hung up on cloned github project Angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to clone a github project. I think I'm having an issue with NPM or package.json.

When I run

```
ng --verison
```

Inside the cloned project I get

```
PS ..\..\ClonedProject> ng --version

Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.800.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            8.0.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      8.0.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             8.0.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.800.1 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.4.0 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
```

If I run

```
ng --version
```

In another project that was created on my local machine (not cloned) I get:

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.1
@angular/cli                      8.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.1
@schematics/angular               8.0.1
@schematics/update                0.800.1
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

SO I was thinking it had something to do with NPM. When I try reinstalling npm in the ClonedProject, npm hangs on rxjs:

```
[            ......] \ extract:rxjs: sill extract rxjs@6.5.2 extracted to C:\..\..\ClonedProject\node_modules\.staging\rxjs-b78e1abc (21998ms)
```

I tried to uninstall npm and reinstall npm and I still get the same issue. I really don't feel like creating a brand new project and copying and pasting everything. Has anyone else run into this issue? I can post more if need been.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-tour-of-hobbies",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.36",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
    "node-vibrant": "^3.1.3",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi CgOnvMM, welcome to StackOverflow! Please create a [_minimal, reproducible example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're facing so that we can help you narrow down your issue. (Please also post your `package.json`)

Comment: Added the package.json

Comment: Did you uninstall NPM itself or did you uninstall the project's dependencies? Did you run `npm i`? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: tried uninstall npm itself, tried uninstalling the project dependencies. Did try npm i. Am behind a proxy. Not sure if the proxy thing matters if I was able to npm i without any issues for another project that was started locally compared to the current issue where I try npm I for a cloned project.